# storm-starter missing class org.apache.storm.localcluster

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-storm

I want to use storm as a solution for processing events.
I Want to forward events from ELK to storm and add some code in storm.

I’ve been trying to run the storm-starter code:
https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter

using Intellij IDEA, but I keep getting error about a missing class: org.apache.storm.localcluster

can you please help with this? am I using the right code? 
I would really appreciate your help with this

Answer (score 0):

Just copying what I answered to user mailing list:
The files which thrift generated are tricky. Please try `mvn clean install -DskipTests` to root of Storm directory, and back to IDEA and see it helps.

Comment: I did, i now get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/storm/topology/IRichSpout
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.storm.topology.IRichSpout
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass...